A question on a generalization of recursively inseparable sets
$\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of natural numbers $0,1,2,\ldots$ In what follows all sets are subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.
The classical definition that two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ are recursively inseparable (r.i.) can be stated as follows: $S_1$ and $S_2$ are r.i., if there exist no two disjoint recursive sets $R_1$ and $R_2$, with $R_1\cup R_2=\mathbb{N}$, such that $(S_1\cap R_1)\cup(S_2\cap R_2)=\emptyset$. Now, this definition can be naturally generalized to arbitrary finite sequences $S_1, S_2,\ldots,S_n$ of $n\geqslant 2$ sets:
$S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_n$ are r.i., if there exist no pairwise disjoint recursive sets $R_1,R_2,\ldots,R_n$, with $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}R_i=\mathbb{N}$, such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}(S_i\cap R_i)=\emptyset$.
It occurred to me to wonder: if $S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_n$ are pairwise r.i., do we have that $S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_n$ are r.i.?
I considered the case $n=3$, and I found that there are in fact three pairwise r.i. sets $S_1,S_2,S_3$ such that $S_1,S_2,S_3$ are not r.i.: $S_1=\{0,1\}$, $S_2=\{0,2\}$ and $S_3=\{1,2\}$. However, this seems trivial to me because $S_1,S_2,S_3$ are not pairwise disjoint.
So, my question is: are there $S_1,S_2,S_3$, with $S_1,S_2,S_3$ pairwise disjoint and pairwise r.i., such that $S_1,S_2,S_3$ are not r.i.?
